# Using related records added on Collector (for ArcGIS) to update original feature class values and symbology

Tags: feature-class, relationship-class, relates, arcgis-collector, one-to-many

I currently use Collector for ArcGIS to carry out tree inspections. The design consists of two parts - a feature class layer which contains a point for each tree including data such as its species, height and last inspection date and a table which contains previous tree inspections. The two parts are related using a 1:many relationship class based on a shared GlobalID field. I used ArcGIS 10.6.1 desktop to create to the relationship class which I then host on ArcGIS Online and subsequently update on Collector for ArcGIS (Based on https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-mobility/field-mobility/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/).

When carrying out tree inspections, I use Collector to add a related record to trees within the original feature class. Is there a way to use the data recorded in the related record to update attributes in the feature class such as 'next inspection date' without having to change this manually?

For example, a tree's last inspection date was 20/09/2018. If I carry out an inspection today and use Collector to add a related record, is there a way to get the feature class to update its 'last inspection date' to 22/09/2019 without having to do this manually for every tree?

Comment: this is an old question, but it seems like you should be about do to this with Survey123 Collect, but it requires you to be using Survey123 as well.